# SQL server Get all columns in a database that exceed 450 Unicode characters or 900 bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get all columns in a database that exceed 450 Unicode characters or 900 bytes (SQL server)

Comment: Do you mean all the column names for which at least one value exists with the length you specified, OR the values themselves?

Comment: I want to know the amount of tables where all columns that are in an index that exceed 450 Unicode characters or 900 bytes.. I need the column names for which at least one value exists.

Comment: Only columns that are part of indexes? So, if a column has such a long value but is not part of the index, you don't want it?

Comment: Yes.i want columns that are part of an index

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to see indexes that would throw the following warning:

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'IndexName'
>   has maximum length of 1900 bytes. For some combination of large
>   values, the insert/update operation will fail.

```
SELECT 
    SchemaName = ss.name, 
    TableName = so.name, 
    IndexName = si.name, 
    KeyColumnMaxLength = SUM(sc.max_length)
FROM 
    sys.objects so 
    JOIN sys.columns sc ON so.object_id = sc.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas ss ON so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
    JOIN sys.indexes si ON sc.object_id = si.object_id
    JOIN sys.index_columns sic ON 
        si.object_id = sic.object_id AND 
        si.index_id = sic.index_id AND 
        sic.column_id = sc.column_id
WHERE
    so.type = 'U' AND 
    sic.is_included_column = 0
GROUP BY 
    ss.name, 
    so.name, 
    si.name
HAVING 
    SUM(sc.max_length) > 900
ORDER BY 
    SUM(sc.max_length) DESC
```

Comment: why are u using SUM(sc.max_length)?

Comment: @AnishAravind because you requested *"where all columns that are in an index exceed 450 Unicode characters or 900 bytes"*. `max_length` gives the size of the column in bytes. Needs to be grouped to check for the sum of all indexed columns by each index.